Overriding or dynamically loading the values of defineNuxtPlugin (Nuxt 3) based on different value for `host`?
How would one go about overriding or dynamically loading the values on defineNuxtPlugin based on different host values?
i18n is my current use case, where I need a different i18n.config.ts for each website, as having all in one is just unscalable.
However, being able to override other settings is also desirable.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
I understand that defineNuxtPlugin is loaded during build time, so I wonder if middleware is a solution?
